# node.js / expressjs simple file upload issue

Tags: node.js, upload, express

I'm working on creating a simple file uploader on a node server with expressjs as the middleware. So far, the server side looks like:

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.files);

    //Handle the file
    fs.readFile(req.files.imageUploader.path, function(err, data) {
        var newPath = __dirname;
        console.log(newPath);
        console.log(data);
        fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function(err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.send("AOK");
        });
    });
});
```

Now, the log statement for `__dirname` is my source directory, as expected (C:\Development\GitHub\ExpressFileUpload), however an error is happening on the upload:

```
{ [Error: EISDIR, open 'C:\Development\GitHub\ExpressFileUpload']
errno: 28,
code: 'EISDIR',
path: 'C:\\Development\\GitHub\\ExpressFileUpload' }
```

I've tried changing the `newPath` to be `/` and `./` but no change, different errors, but still errors. Is it something to do with the double `\\` in the `path` in the error? Am I missing something simple here? Thanks for the help, let me know if more info is needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `__dirname` global object is a directory, not a file. Therefore, you can't open it for writing, which is what `fs.writeFile()` attempts to do in your script, hence the reason you are getting a `EISDIR`. Assuming you want the file to be written with the same name it was uploaded with, you can do this:

```
var file = req.files.imageUploader;
fs.readFile(file.path, function(err, data) {
  var path = __dirname + '/' + file.name;
  fs.writeFile(path, data, function(err) {
  });
});
```

Comment: Same thing yet, except now my `console.log(data)` statement is reading `undefined`, before it was pulling in the data and listing the chunks.

Comment: Ignore my original answer, the information was applied to the wrong part of your code.

Comment: Yep, that was it! Thanks for the help! (55 seconds and ill mark it, have a +1 for now)